# How to call a jar file and execute his class on a NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jar

I have a question about how can i call a external .jar file and use the class that is inside of it, inside my NodeJS backend.

I found something about a npm-java here on the stackoverflow but i wasn't able to execute the .jar file and use the class that comes inside of it ? is there any other alternative ? i also thought about using websocket and creating a java application on a new port to communicate with my NodeJS api in another port.

Comment: Would executing `java -jar whatever.jar` as you would execute any other external command be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Hi Federico, i tried using the .jar file with command lines but i actually need the classes that are inside of it to decrypt a cookie. basically i just need to access one method inside of the class that is inside of the .jar file and get a decrypted cookie.

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done. To make it simple I would create a simple java command line utility that leverages those classes and methods in the jar and call that command line utility from the js app as an external command.

Comment: That was a alternative that i thought at first i tried calling the .jar with the following command (java -cp jarfile.jar "firstParamater" "secondParameter) but it didn't returned anything from me, I think that I need to call the method inside of it directly